# How to restart bluetooth shield in arduino uno programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I needed to connect my arduino uno board to android mobile via bluetooth. I used bluetooth shield for arduino. My android application could be able to communicate with the arduino and successfully exchanged data between. I want to know how to close this bluetooth connection. That is, when i click a button (say 'close' button) in the android app, it should close the connection, then the arduino will get close the connection and be capable for another connections. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install spp serial port protocool Manager on your android. This app has the disconnect button.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It has zero information in how to code on either side or the functions that would make it possible.